# Multi-room availability for Sabre HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ

Tags: sabre

Sabre allows you to specify the number of rooms to book when processing a booking via OTA_HotelResRQ. However, I cannot see any data points within the response of HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ telling me how many rooms are available. Nor can I specify how many rooms I'd like to check for availability when performing a HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ.

This is troublesome when booking multi-rooms as I have no idea whether more than 1 is actually available. Is my request incorrect? Is their a workaround? Please advise.

**Example HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <From>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01"><!-- removed by op --></PartyId>
         </From>
         <To>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Sabre</PartyId>
         </To>
         <CPAId><!-- removed by op --></CPAId>
         <ConversationId>MyConversationID</ConversationId>
         <Service type="sabreXML">HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</Service>
         <Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</Action>
         <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1422291197</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2015-01-26T09:53:17-07:00</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2015-01-26T10:53:17-07:00</TimeToLive>
         </MessageData>
      </MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <!-- removed by op -->
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="2.0.1">
         <AvailRequestSegment>
            <GuestCounts Count="2" />
            <HotelSearchCriteria>
                <Criterion>
                    <HotelRef HotelCode="0007625" />

                </Criterion>
            </HotelSearchCriteria>

            <TimeSpan Start="02-19" End="02-24" />
         </AvailRequestSegment>
      </HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Example Response (truncated a bit due to size):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="URI"><!-- removed by op --></eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId><!-- removed by op --></eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>MyConversationID</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Service><eb:Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>10532827796103670873</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2016-09-21T22:06:51</eb:Timestamp><eb:RefToMessageId>1422291197</eb:RefToMessageId></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><!-- removed by op --></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><HotelPropertyDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2011/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.0.1">
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="Complete">
  <stl:Success timeStamp="2016-09-21T17:06:51-05:00"/>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
 <RoomStay>
  <BasicPropertyInfo ChainCode="HX" GeoConfidenceLevel="1" HotelCityCode="SLC" HotelCode="0007625" HotelName="HAMPTON INN STES PARK CITY" Latitude="40.727734" Longitude="-111.54821" NumFloors="4" RPH="001">
   <Address>
    <AddressLine>6609 NORTH LANDMARK DRIVE</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>PARK CITY UT 84098</AddressLine>
    <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
   </Address>
   <Award Provider="NTM2 CROWN"/>
   <ContactNumbers>
    <ContactNumber Fax="1-435-645-9672" Phone="1-435-645-0900"/>
   </ContactNumbers>
   <DirectConnect Ind="false">
    <AdditionalData Ind="true"/>
    <CurrencyConverted Ind="true"/>
    <DC_AvailParticipant Ind="true"/>
    <DC_SellParticipant Ind="true"/>
    <RequestFail Ind="false"/>
    <UnAvail Ind="false"/>
   </DirectConnect>
   <IndexData>
    <Index CountryState="UT" DistanceDirection="32E" LocationCode="C" Point="DELTA CENTER" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index CountryState="UT" DistanceDirection="6N" LocationCode="A" Point="PARK CITY" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index CountryState="UT" DistanceDirection="33E" LocationCode="C" Point="TEMPLE SQUARE" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index CountryState="UT" DistanceDirection="6S" LocationCode="A" Point="PARK CITY SKI AREA" TransportationCode="O"/>
    <Index DistanceDirection="35W" LocationCode="C" Point="SLC" TransportationCode="O"/>
   </IndexData>
   <SpecialOffers Ind="false"/>
   <Taxes>
    <Text>9.35PCT TT</Text>
   </Taxes>
  </BasicPropertyInfo>
  <RoomRates>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A0ALV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="001" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>2 QUEEN BEDS NONSMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/HOT BREAKFAST INCLUDED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="409.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2236.21">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="191.21"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A05LV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="002" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING BED NONSMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/HOT BREAKFAST INCLUDED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="409.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2236.21">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="191.21"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A06LV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="003" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING BED 1BDRM SUITE W/ KITCHEN NONSMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/LIVING ROOM/SOFABED/</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="429.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2345.56">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="200.56"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A08LV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="004" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>2 QUEEN BEDS SMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/HOT BREAKFAST INCLUDED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="409.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2236.21">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="191.21"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A02LV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="005" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING BED SMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/HOT BREAKFAST INCLUDED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="409.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2236.21">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="191.21"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A03LV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="006" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING BED 1 BEDROOM SUITE W/ KITCHEN SMOKING</Text>
     <Text>2 HDTVS/FREE WI-FI/HOT BREAKFAST INCLUDED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="429.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2345.56">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="200.56"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A0FLV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="007" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING MOBILITY ACCESS WITH TUB NONSMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/WORK AREA</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="409.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2236.21">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="191.21"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A0CLV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="008" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING MOBILITY ACCESS ROLL IN SHOWER NOSMOK</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/WORK AREA</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="409.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2236.21">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="191.21"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A0DLV4" IATA_ProductIdentification="BEST AVAILABLE RATE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="009" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING MOBILITY/HEARING ACCESS TUB SUITE NS</Text>
     <Text>VIS FIREALRM/DOOR/PHN ALRT/SOFABED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="429.00" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2345.56">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="200.56"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A0AAE0" IATA_ProductIdentification="2X POINTS PACKAGE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="010" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>2 QUEEN BEDS NONSMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/HOT BREAKFAST INCLUDED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="441.72" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2415.10">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="206.50"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A05AE0" IATA_ProductIdentification="2X POINTS PACKAGE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="011" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING BED NONSMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/HOT BREAKFAST INCLUDED</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="441.72" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2415.10">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="206.50"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
   </RoomRate>
   <RoomRate DirectConnect="false" GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="D" GuaranteedRateProgram="false" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" IATA_CharacteristicIdentification="A06AE0" IATA_ProductIdentification="2X POINTS PACKAGE" LowInventoryThreshold="false" RPH="012" RateChangeInd="false" RateConversionInd="false" SpecialOffer="false">
    <AdditionalInfo>
     <CancelPolicy Numeric="30" Option="D"/>
     <Commission NonCommission="false">COMMISSIONABLE</Commission>
     <Text>1 KING BED 1BDRM SUITE W/ KITCHEN NONSMOKING</Text>
     <Text>HDTV/FREE WI-FI/LIVING ROOM/SOFABED/</Text>
    </AdditionalInfo>
    <Rates>
     <Rate Amount="463.32" ChangeIndicator="false" CurrencyCode="USD" HRD_RequiredForSell="false" PackageIndicator="false" RateConversionInd="false" ReturnOfRateInd="false" RoomOnRequest="false">
      <AdditionalGuestAmounts>
       <AdditionalGuestAmount MaxExtraPersonsAllowed="0" NumAdults="0" NumCribs="0">
        <Charges AdultRollAway="10.00" Crib="0.00" ExtraPerson="10.00"/>
       </AdditionalGuestAmount>
      </AdditionalGuestAmounts>
      <HotelTotalPricing Amount="2533.20">
       <Disclaimer>INCLUDES TAXES AND SURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <Disclaimer>EXCLUDES INCIDENTALSURCHARGES</Disclaimer>
       <TotalTaxes Amount="216.60"/>
      </HotelTotalPricing>
     </Rate>
    </Rates>
  </RoomRates>
  <TimeSpan Duration="0005" End="2017-01-24" Start="2017-01-19"/>
 </RoomStay>
</HotelPropertyDescriptionRS></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually how it works, and I think it is a limitation of the hotel GDSs, since I believe most don't allow multi room availability requests.

When you search for hotel availability you just select the number of guests that will be staying and hotels return the rooms that would fit that many people. If 2 guests are requested, hotels might return 1 room for 2 people or 2 rooms.

As you say, you can only request the amount of rooms at the time of sale.

Comment: It really is one of the worst web services I've ever dealt with.